# Repository became unforked and I'm not sure what caused it but want it to be forked

Tags: git, github

I had a repository forked from a team repository. I just pushed changes to it and when I looked in github I saw that it was no longer forked. I don't know what I've done for this to occur. I performed these steps at a command line:

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "Message"
git push
```

Then I saw that one file was not staged for commit so I did this:

```
git add "../Filepath/File.cs"
git commit -m "Message"
git push
```

Did I do something incorrectly that would have caused the forked repository to no longer be forked? I want to merge my updates with the team repository, what should I do now?

Last time this occurred, I did all of this to fix it but I was hoping there was something simpler:

```
1.) back up current project locally
2.) delete project locally
3.) delete previously forked repository
4.) fork repository again
5.) clone forked repository locally
6.) copy backed up files to cloned location
7.) push files to personal repository
8.) merge personal repository to team repository
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GitHub "fork" is a clone.  The only thing special about using the "fork" button *on* GitHub is that it does some extra behind-the-scenes items *on* GitHub itself:

- It lets them save space.  (The exact mechanism here is hidden from you: your fork otherwise behaves like any ordinary clone.)
- It lets *you* raise "pull requests", whereby commits you have pushed to your GitHub fork become available to whoever controls the repository you forked, along with all of the issue-tracking and email-generating stuff that GitHub provide as a whole ecosystem around this.

That second bullet point is the true selling point of a GitHub fork.  It's why we use the fork button, rather than just making a clone.  The first bullet point is great for *GitHub* but does nothing for GitHub's *users*.

But, because both actions are entirely behind-the-scenes, there's nothing *you* can do that affects either one.  Only GitHub themselves can "unhook" the hookups they made that enable that second bullet point.

Typically this happens if whoever owns the repository in question deletes it.  Suppose, for instance, I use the GitHub button to fork repository R, owned by owner O.  Then owner O decides there's something terrible about R, so they delete R entirely.  There's nowhere for *me* to send my requests *to* now, so GitHub undo the connection they made between my fork F and O's R.

If owner O now creates a *new* project named R, and I go looking about, I'll see that R "still exists", and somehow my fork F has "disconnected" from R.  The real problem here is that the R I see now is not the R I saw yesterday.  Oh, sure, they have the same names.  They may even have the same *contents* (down to the raw commit hash IDs).  But they're completely different repositories, just as that replica of the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) made by copying each molecule precisely is still a totally different ship.

Now, if you can talk to the owner O and find out that they *didn't* do anything, we must conclude that somehow GitHub unhooked things; to resolve the obvious followup questions ("how" and "why") we'd have to ask the GitHub folks.

Comment: The part about the owner doing something was absolutely correct, although I didn't notice it was happening for a couple months. I just happened see the word 'Private' next to some repos I had forked and didn't remember seeing that before. I created a Public repo, forked it then changed to Private and saw my fork disappear. Then I talked to our github admin who told me he changes all of the repos to Private. So, you were right but it took me a while to figure out what was happening.